# NativeQuery for Postgres

Tags: vba, postgresql

I just migrated data from Firebird to PostgreSQL and now face the following issue: there are some VBA macros and if the macro contains such a line:

```
set a_obj = GSQuery.NativeQuery("Select A_ID as aid from Objekte where OBJ_ID = "& obj_personal.ObjectID)
```

it doesn't work in PostgreSQL.

Changing Select / as / from / where... to capital letters doesn't bring anything.
What else did I forget?

Comment: What is `GSQuery`? What error do you get?

Comment: GSQuery = object, whic allows to perform operations on the GS database. GS is the application. The application shows only the line, column and the error's#, where the error occurs and this is just the line I posted above